# Where is the logs in Camel K integration pod

Tags: apache-camel, apache-camel-k

**Update**

```
# access to the container
kubectl exec -it -c integration my-route-80b4cb7566-v6l7m /bin/sh

# go to directory
cd /tmp
```

Both the answers of Squake and Nicola are working properly. To check the generate logging file, you need to access to the container and check the right directory:

**Original Question**

I have an integration pod running with kamel:

```
kamel run MyRoute.java
```

I have log in the route

```
from("...")
.log("my log message")
```

I am able to check the log lines with command:

```
kubectl logs my-route-85d7f65c96-rmb4z --tail=10
```

Then I am able to access to the pod using:

```
kubectl exec -it -c integration my-route-85d7f65c96-rmb4z /bin/sh
```

I tried to check folder `/var/log`, unfortunately there's no related log files.

I have 2 questions on this:

- Where is the log file location in the integration pod?
- How can I specify log file location?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default, the integration only logs into standard output, so that logs can be gathered by Kubernetes.

You can provide advanced logging configuration using Quarkus properties.

E.g. Create a `logging.properties` file with the following content:

```
quarkus.log.file.enable=true
quarkus.log.file.path=/tmp/camel.log
quarkus.log.file.level=INFO
```

Then run the integration with:

```
kamel run MyRoute.java --property=file:logging.properties
```

You'll find a `camel.log` file under `/tmp` with the INFO logs. You can find more examples here: https://quarkus.io/guides/logging.

You can write logs to any dir where the process has write access, including you own PV if needed.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, it works like a charm!

Answer (score 3):

A Camel K Integration works like any Camel Quarkus application, so, we must provide the proper [settings as expected by Camel Quarkus](https://quarkus.io/guides/logging#quarkus-log-logging-log-config_quarkus.log.file):

```
kamel run Sample.java --dev -p quarkus.log.file.path=/tmp/trace.log -p quarkus.log.file.enable=true
```

The default is to have the log to standard output stream. You can configure adding all the properties needed. Certain configuration are also present in the [logging trait](https://camel.apache.org/camel-k/next/traits/logging.html).

Comment: Thank you Squake for your answer, it works!